# Spring JMX proxy interface issue

Tags: spring, jmx, spring-jmx, mbeanexporter

I'm trying out Spring + JMX bean configuration in my project. I'm new to JMX technology. I need to implement the proxyinterface way in managed beans. When tried, I'm getting the below mentioned error.

Can anyone guide me? I'm trying out to deploy my war in tomcat. On the context initialization of the applicaiton on startup, I'm getting **InvalidInvocationException**

**Interface**

```
package my.pjt.test.location;

public interface AppResourceLocationMBean {

    String getLocation();

    void setLocation(String location);
}
```

**Implementing class**

```
package my.pjt.test.location;

public class AppResourceLocation implements AppResourceLocationMBean {

    private volatile String location = "classpath:**/app-resource/**/";

    @Override public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @Override public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

**Used in AppLoader**

```
package my.pjt.test.location;

public class AppLoader {

    private volatile AppResourceLocationMBean appLocationMBean;

     public void init() throws Exception {
        ...........
        String appLocation = this.appLocationMBean.getLocation();
        ..........  
    }
}
```

**service.xml snippet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-init-method="init"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:integration-jmx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx"
    xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    ">


    <context:component-scan base-package="my.pjt.test"/>

    <context:mbean-export />

    <bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.sproingframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
        <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="appConfigLocationMBean" class="org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="objectName" value="test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001"/>
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="my.pjt.test.location.AppResourceLocationMBean"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="appLoader" class="my.pjt.test.location.AppLoader">
        <property name="appLocationMBean" ref="appConfigLocationMBean" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mbeanExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
        <property name="beans">
          <map>
            <entry key="test:name=appLoader" value-ref="appLoader"/>
          </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Full Stack trace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException|Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/service.xml]:Cannot resolve reference to bean 'appLoader' while setting bean property 'beans' with key [TypedStringValue: value [test:name=appLoader], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appLoader' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.access.InvalidInvocationException: test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appLoader' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.access.InvalidInvocationException: test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 47 more

Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.access.InvalidInvocationException:
 test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001
    at org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanClientInterceptor.doInvoke(MBeanClientInterceptor.java:445)
    at org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanClientInterceptor.invoke(MBeanClientInterceptor.java:353)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy17.getLocation(Unknown Source)
    at my.pjt.test.location.AppLoader.init(AppLoader.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 54 more

Nov 12, 2014 4:10:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /test threw load() exception
org.springframework.jmx.access.InvalidInvocationException: 
test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001
    at org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanClientInterceptor.doInvoke(MBeanClientInterceptor.java:445)
    at org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanClientInterceptor.invoke(MBeanClientInterceptor.java:353)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy17.getLocation(Unknown Source)
    at my.pjt.test.location.AppLoader.init(AppLoader.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Added Try-Catch in init() and print the stack trace(see below)

```
  Exception ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    org.springframework.jmx.access.InvalidInvocationException: test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001
        at org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanClientInterceptor.doInvoke(MBeanClientInterceptor.java:445)
        at org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanClientInterceptor.invoke(MBeanClientInterceptor.java:353)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy17.getLocation(Unknown Source)
        at my.pjt.test.location.AppLoader.init(AppLoader.java:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:829)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:718)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1147)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)


     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

OperationException() results in getLocation()

```
OperationsException ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
javax.management.OperationsException
    at my.pjt.test.location.AppResourceLocation.getLocation(AppResourceLocation.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:111)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:45)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:235)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:83)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:204)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:668)
    at com.metatv.application.management.ManagedObjectSupport.createMBeanDocument(ManagedObjectSupport.java:612)
    at com.metatv.application.management.ManagedObjectSupport.store(ManagedObjectSupport.java:568)
    at com.metatv.application.management.ManagedObjectSupport.store(ManagedObjectSupport.java:539)
    at com.metatv.application.management.ManagedObjectSupport.store(ManagedObjectSupport.java:523)
    at com.metatv.application.management.ManagementServletContextListener.storeMBeans(ManagementServletContextListener.java:341)
    at com.metatv.application.management.ManagementServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ManagementServletContextListener.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Edit: I'm still facing issues. I created a sample project in https://github.com/appu-86/JMX-Test. Can anyone help/hint me what could be reason with proxy interface issue in the sample project?

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace.

Comment: Gary, I've added full stack trace

Comment: There's no root cause in the trace; I suggest you put a try/catch in `init()` and print the stack trace, so we can see the real problem. Adding `throws OperationsException` to `getLocation()` might work too.

Comment: Added try-catch in init() and updated it in my question. Any hint to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm; that didn't help; sorry - I think we need to try adding the `throws OperationsException` to get the root cause.

Comment: uploaded throws OperationsException() results

Comment: One additional input is that, the AppResourceLocationMBean and its implementing class is from a dependency jar, which is present in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Now you need to figure out what's happening here:       at my.pjt.test.location.AppResourceLocation.getLocation(AppResourceLocation.java:28) - it's in your code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to debug. I'll debug further more and let you know the results

Comment: Hi, as suspected it didn't seems like an issue in AppResourceLocation.getLocation() method. I've added logs in getLocation() and observed that it is called twice. Method simply returns the location value as shown above. During contextinitialization of war it get called(stacktrace below) with valid details. But when called from Apploader.init() -->AppLocationMbean.getLocation() it fails with InvalidInvocationException

Comment: my.pjt.test.location.AppResourceLocation.getLocation(AppResourceLocation.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:111)

Comment: at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:45)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:235)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.getAttribute(PerInterface.java:83)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.getAttribute(MBeanSupport.java:204)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:647)  
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:668)

Comment: Well, as you can see from the last stack trace in your question, the `OperationsException` is thrown even when it's not called from your `init()` method.

Comment: Yes. In that case also, it is not called from init(). It is called during context initialization. Am I missing any configuration in service.xml ?

Comment: So you need to figure out why; it's not a Spring issue.

Comment: Garry, not able to sort it out till yet. I've added a simple sample project having proxy interface issue in the question session. Could you please share your suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying with your sample; when I added `throws OperationException` as I suggested, I get...

```
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001
```

This comment makes no sense:

```
<!-- Enabling below bean and disabling the above bean worked for me. But need a proxy interface solution. -->
```

The proxy is a a **proxy** for the real MBean not a replacement for it - the MBean has to exist in the server.

There is no such MBean "test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001" - you can see that by opening VisualVM or JConsole.

However, even with the MBean defined, the root cause of your problem is that you are trying to access it from an `init()` method before the context is loaded.

Here is a revised version of your test context that works just fine because I removed the reference to the apploader in the MBeanExporter and moved the appLoader to below the MBeanExporter.

```
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="appConfigLocationMBean" class="org.springframework.jmx.access.MBeanProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="objectName" value="test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="com.my.config.app_loader.AppResourceLocationMBean"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enabling below bean and disabling the above bean worked for me. But need a proxy interface solution. -->
<bean id="actualAppConfigLocationMBean" class="com.my.config.app_loader.AppResourceLocation"/>       

 <bean id="mbeanExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="beans">
      <map>
    <!--  Used to add additional application contexts at runtime. --> 
       <entry key="test:name=appLocationConfiguration,type=SpringAppLocationConfiguration,context=pjt001"
              value-ref="actualAppConfigLocationMBean" />
      </map>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="appLoader" class="com.my.config.app_loader.AppLoader">
    <property name="appLocationMBean" ref="appConfigLocationMBean" />
</bean>
```

However, I would recommend implementing `SmartLifecycle` and do the lookup in `start()` rather than `init()`, because then you can be sure that all the beans in the context have been initialized.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gary ! I'm able to load all MBeans successfully using the mentioned changes. I've updated my work sample https://github.com/appu-86/JMX-Test.git with the latest changes so that it help all to refer it later. I'm a beginner in JMX and your inputs like how to debug(OperationException) and SmartLifeCycle really helped me to move forward. Thanks once again !!